# Segmentation fault using multiple structs

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm kinda new in C. I'm having some trouble using pointers and stuff like that.

I made this piece of code to try to understand why does it return me Segmentation Fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct lligada {

    int userID;

    struct lligada *prox;

} *LInt;

typedef struct {

   int repo_id;
   LInt users;

} Repo;


typedef struct nodo_repo {

   Repo repo;

   struct nodo_repo *left; 
   struct nodo_repo *right; 

} *ABin_Repos;



void createList (int id_user, int id_repo) {
   ABin_Repos temp = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_repo));

   temp->repo.repo_id = id_repo;
   temp->repo.users->userID = id_user;

   temp->left = NULL;
   temp->right = NULL;

   printf("%d", temp->repo.users->userID);
}

int main() {
 
    int id_user, id_repo;

    scanf("%d %d", &id_user, &id_repo);

    createList(id_user, id_repo);

  return 0;
}
```

I really don't understand.
Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thank you!

Comment: i would run your program thru something like valgrind and it should tell you what is wrong.

Comment: The field: `Lint users;` is a pointer to a structure. You would need to use `malloc` for a `lligada` structure. It's worth taking time to learn how to examine data using a debugger for these sorts of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `users` is `LInt` and `LInt` is an alias of type `struct lligada *`:

```
typedef struct lligada {
    int userID;    
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;
```

That means the type of `users` is `struct lligada *`.
In the `createList()`, you are accessing `users` pointer before allocating it. Hence, you are getting segmentation fault.

You should do:

```
void createList (int id_user, int id_repo) {
   ABin_Repos temp = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo_repo));

   // Allocate memory to users
   temp->repo.users = malloc (sizeof (struct lligada));
   // check malloc return
   if (temp->repo.users == NULL) {
       // handle memory allocation failure
       exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   temp->repo.repo_id = id_repo;
   temp->repo.users->userID = id_user;

   .....
   .....
```

Additional:
Follow good programming practice, make sure to check returned value of function like `scanf()` and `malloc()`.